# TextWatcher caused crash

Tags: android, textwatcher

Here's a newbie to Android Developing.

While I'm making an app that calculate the calories burnt from exercise, I found that adding a TextWatcher to the EditText will cause crashing even I only add it on the "etEnergy".

I've searched many questions about crashed, but most of them are making a infinity loop in the listener and solved by remove the listener then add it back later. I added that but it doesn't work.

I found this message in Logcat when I can't find the log I made in the method:

Warning ActivityManager(744): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41ea1128 u0 [package name]/.MainActivity t65 f}

The following are the problem codes in MainActivity.java. Without them I can execute correctly but I need them to complete this app.

```
protected EditText etEnergy,etWeight,etTime;
protected TextView tvCals;
//double t,a; //don't make any sense in following code.
myTextWatch tw;

class myTextWatch implements TextWatcher{

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        etEnergy.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        etWeight.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        etTime.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        Log.d("TextWatcher","TextChangedListenerRemoved");
        etEnergy.addTextChangedListener(this);
        etWeight.addTextChangedListener(this);
        etTime.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}//end of class myTextWatch

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etEnergy=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnergy);
    etWeight=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
    etTime=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTime);
    etEnergy.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    etWeight.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    etTime.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    tvCals=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCals);
}
```

Almost forgot to say that I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 and app will be run on a physical device which is a HTC Butterfly that the Android version is 4.4.2 and the minimum API Level of the app is 14(IceCreamSandwich/4.0).

English is not my native language but I'll try hard to read any reply.

Thanks for your reading.
Also appreciates for your answering!

Comment: Why are you removing then re-adding listeners whenever the text changes?

Comment: i suggested to you another way please try and report

Comment: Make sure your `EditText`'s are not null.

Comment: @PPartisan It can prevent the infinity loop from editing the text in the method of `TextWatcher`.It will trigger the listener while editing without removing the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `EditText`'s are null. Please make sure that in `activity_main` layout you have `EditText`'s with following ids: `etEnergy, etWeight, etTime`

And as a side note - you're not actually creating a new object of your `myTextWatch` and trying to pass null in `addTextChangedListener(tw)`.

Comment: So it's just a simple java question that I didn't call the constructor.the `EditText`s are not null but the `TextWather` was.Thanks a lot!

Comment: What I did actually is adding `=new myTextWatch();` while declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected EditText etEnergy,etWeight,etTime;
    protected TextView tvCals;
    //double t,a; //don't make any sense in following code.
    TextWatch tw;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etEnergy=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnergy);
    etWeight=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
    etTime=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTime);
    etEnergy.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    etWeight.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    etTime.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    tvCals=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCals);
}

tw= new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        etEnergy.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        etWeight.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        etTime.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        Log.d("TextWatcher","TextChangedListenerRemoved");
        etEnergy.addTextChangedListener(this);
        etWeight.addTextChangedListener(this);
        etTime.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};//end of class myTextWatch
```

Comment: Thanks! It's another way to call the constructor.